# How to apend data in previous line after finding the pattern using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find the pattern and add/append the data in that line and the below data will shift one line.

Below is the input text file:

```
qa
ws
jk
***
hg
se
xc
```

Below is the python code:

```
lookup = '***'

with open("./sample.txt", 'rw+') as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile):
        if lookup in line:
            #not sure what code should be there 
            #to write the data in the num position 
            #or in the above case new data(rs is added) should be 
            #append in line no: 4
```

Final expected output(same input file) text file should be:

```
qa
ws
jk
rs
***
hg
se
xc
```

Comment: post the final result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Added the final output.

Comment: moreover, the final output shows that additional action is intended: modify the line **next** to pattern. Extend your question to cover all conditions

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
lookup = '***'

def f():
    with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().split('\n')
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.endswith(lookup):
            lines[idx] = line.replace(lookup, 'rs')
            break
    idx += 1
    lines.insert(idx, str(idx) + '.' + lookup)
    for delta, line in enumerate(lines[idx:]):
        suffix = '.' + line.split('.')[1]
        lines[idx + delta] = str(idx + delta + 1) + suffix
    return lines

print(f())
```

sample.txt is:

```
1.qa
2.ws
3.jk
4.***
5.hg
6.se
7.xc
```

Comment: I am getting below error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rwa_file.py", line 58, in <module>
    print(f())
  File "rwa_file.py", line 54, in f
    suffix = '.' + line.split('.')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: Also, sorry for not writing correct input and correct output, I have changed the data.